# The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, centos8

I'm trying to install certbot. I'm using Centos8 and following instructions from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-8

The error occurs when I run `sudo certbot --nginx` The error I get is:

> The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing config                                                                             uration.
> The error was: NoInstallationError("Could not find a usable 'nginx' binary.
> Ensure nginx exists, the binary is executable, and your PATH is set correctly.",)

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem.  were you able to solve this?